# Material only applies to some of the Mesh

Tags: materials, append

Finished 60% of my character, I made the head separately from the body, I used "append" option to bring the head into the body scene and then merge it.

For some reason, even after connecting  the neck vertices to the head, when I add skin material, it only applies to the head and not the rest of the body, I don't know why this happens, I select everything but only the head changes.

[image]

BTW the head mesh looks more glossy than the body , I don't know what caused this

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rest of the body is part of a different material slot, the last one, in fact.

[image: The material slot with the rest of the body]

You can either:

- Assign the material to both texture slots
- Merge the texture slots to the same slot

To merge:

1. Go to edit mode
2. Go to the materials tab
3. Click the last material slot
4. Click the "Select" Button under the material slot listings
5. Click The first material slot (the one currently with the material)
6. Click "Select" again
7. Click "Assign"

To Assign:

1. Go to edit mode
2. Go to the materials tab
3. Click the last material slot
4. Click the color globe (Next to "+ New")
5. Choose the material